# Microsoft Excel 2007 put values of 2 rows into one 1 row

Tags: excel

I have 2 rows in excel.  One row contains a date and the second contains a time.  I would like to put these two values into another row. When it is text it's ok but date its not working. Has anyoone got a solution?

Comment: A small sample would be useful. And do you only have two rows to combine, or a number of paired rows to combine etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in excel 2007:

If your first row (cell A1) contains `5/12/11`  (typed in just like that; excel automatically formats this cell as date) and 
your second row (cell A2) contains `3:43`  (typed in just like that; excel automatically formats this as time)

Then

type `=A1 + A2` in cell A3

Cell A3 returns `5/12/2011 3:43`, automatically formatted as m/d/yyyy h:mm

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the cell you're moving it into to have date/time formatting.  Right click on it, press "format cell" or whatever's the last option, and chose your desired format.  You can do it for the whole column too if you like by clicking the letter at the top.